# Handle Long Press of Media Button Play/Pause on bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyevent, long-press

I am working on a project for which I want to handle long press of my play button on bluetooth device.
For now it is working for a single click.

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

```
    String intentAction = intent.getAction();
    if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
        return;
    }
    KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (event == null) {
        return;
    }

    int action = event.getAction();
    if (event.getKeyCode() == 126 || event.getKeyCode() == 127) {
        // do something 
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            Toast.makeText(context,"BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(event.isLongPress()==true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Finally long press worked!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }


    }
}
```

The method isLongPress() always returns false.
Please let me what modification can make this program work.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

check the instruction of your BT device. Longpress calling key on headset usually means rejecting an incoming call. I am not sure if longpress Play key on headset is defined in AVRCP.

Comment: theres a different button for answering/rejecting calls

Comment: 1. Why is the key code 126 or 127? The key code of MEDIA_PLAY is 200, see http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/data/keyboards/AVRCP.kl#17.
2. I am not sure if longpress is supported for the keys in AVRCP. You can try it.

Comment: I am quiet sure that the number is 126 for play.And since I have a common button to play and pause I have to consider 127(for pause) as well.Do you know that isLongPress() is the right method used here?

Comment: I don't know if longpress of PLAY key on the BT device as AVRCP controller is supported. If you want to get the answer, you have to analyze the Input manager in Android Framework. You can find the code in http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/native/services/inputflinger/